# Dependency Injection and Scope?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am working the the latest ASP.Net Core RC2, Web API, targeting Windows only. Framework 4.6.1.

I'm confused as to the role of the standard repository pattern is versus the way Core handles controller dependency injection.  I just want to make sure this is the right approach still, as there is not much documentation out there (or it will contradict).

The way I have this set up now, I have a standard repository interface for CRUD operations and the associated class that implements these operations.

I am injecting the *repository* into the controller.  The two steps I have taken are (in `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices()`):

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyCustomRepository, MyCustomRepository>();
```

My controller then is taking in the repository:

```
public MyCustomController(IMyCustomRepository repository) { }
```

My end goal is to get EF Core in here, including the InMemoryProvider.

Is this built correctly so far?  One of my main concerns is that I constantly am reading about how repository patterns are not necessary when using ORMs like Entity Framework, but am unsure how this applies to EF Core.

I've read that you are not supposed to use the AddSingleton here if you are using EF Core, because that depends on a DbContext which is Scoped (so you should use that instead)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application requires singleton behavior, use it. But in that case, you'll have
to manage your object’s lifetime in the class yourself. "However, Entity Framework contexts should be 
added to the services container using the Scoped lifetime. This is taken care of automatically 
if you use the helper methods as shown" below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
    )
}
```

Repositories that will make use of Entity Framework should use the same lifetime; that is, AddScoped...
So your code should be like so:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyCustomRepository, MyCustomRepository>();
```

"One of my main concerns is that I constantly am reading about how repository patterns are not 
necessary when using ORMs like Entity Framework, but am unsure how this applies to EF Core."

You should impliment the repository pattern in your appliation... You should read what is the

repository pattern, and then see if the DbContext and DbSet fulfill it.

Watch this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM

Comment: Thanks.  Where does the `MyDbContext` "live" with the repository pattern?  I've seen examples all over the map.  I specifically want to know about Core RC2.  Is this supposed to be injected into the repository and stored as a member?  I've also seen it wrapped in `using()` blocks on-demand.

Comment: @Patrick: You shouldn't be using `using` blocks in an web application with dependency injection/IoC container, as the container will be disposed after leaving the `using` block and all further access to it during the same request will fail with an exception. ASP.NET Core will take care of the disposing, once the request is finished (assuming you registered it with scoped lifetime)

Comment: @Tseng Agreed.  Should the DbContext be injected into the repository via the constructor in this setup, and stored as a member?

Comment: Yes. It will still be disposed at the end of the request. Just no `using` blocks, the ASP.NET stack takes care of it. At the end of request it will check out any scoped dependencies if they implement `IDisposable` and dispose it